# Should my Switch statment exit with break or return x in this case?

Tags: java, android

In my app the user can select a text and style it with the options as seen on the image. While looking at my code, I wondered if all my switch statement's cases statements shall `break`or `return true/false` and if it has any impact at all? I can see by using `Log.d();` that `break` goes out of the switch method and using `return` stays in the switch

So in this case does it matter what happends in the cases?

[image]

**The method with the Switch cases:**

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.textcolor:

                f3 = ColorPickerDialogFrag2.newInstance(3, Color.WHITE);
                f3.setStyle(android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme);
                f3.show(fragmentManager, "d");

                f3.setListener(this);

                break;


            //--------------------BOLD----------------------------
            case R.id.bold:

                styleSpans = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, StyleSpan.class);

                for (int i = 0; i < styleSpans.length; i++) {
                    if (styleSpans[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD) {
                        str.removeSpan(styleSpans[i]);
                        exists = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!exists) {
                    str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), selectionStart, selectionEnd,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                }

                editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

                return true;
            //--------------------ITALIC----------------------------
            case R.id.italic:

                styleSpans = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, StyleSpan.class);

                for (int i = 0; i < styleSpans.length; i++) {
                    if (styleSpans[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC) {
                        str.removeSpan(styleSpans[i]);
                        exists = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!exists) {
                    str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC), selectionStart, selectionEnd,
                            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                }

                editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "italic");
                break;
            //--------------------UNDERLINE----------------------------
            case R.id.underline:

                UnderlineSpan[] underSpan = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, UnderlineSpan.class);

                for (int i = 0; i < underSpan.length; i++) {
                    str.removeSpan(underSpan[i]);
                    exists = true;
                }


                if (!exists) {
                    str.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                }

                editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "underline");
                return true;

            //--------------------STROKE----------------------------
            case R.id.stroke:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "stroke");
                android.text.style.StrikethroughSpan[] strokeSpan = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, android.text.style.StrikethroughSpan.class);

                for (int i = 0; i < strokeSpan.length; i++) {
                    str.removeSpan(strokeSpan[i]);
                    exists = true;
                }

                if (!exists) {
                    str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StrikethroughSpan(), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                }

                editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

                return false;

            case R.id.increase:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "increase");
                str.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.1f), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

                break;

            case R.id.decrease:

                str.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.9f), selectionStart, selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                editText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

                break;

            case android.R.id.cut:

                CharSequence charSequence = editText.getText().subSequence(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", charSequence);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                editText.getText().replace(selectionStart, selectionEnd, "");
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.toastCopy, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

            case android.R.id.copy:

                charSequence = editText.getText().subSequence(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
                clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                clip = ClipData.newPlainText("simple text", charSequence);
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.toastCopy, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;

            case R.id.textfont:

                FontFragment fontFragment = new FontFragment(selectionStart, selectionEnd, editText);
                fontFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.CustomDialog);
                fontFragment.show(fragmentManager, "fontfragment");

                break;
        }
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "out of switch");
    return true;

}
```

Comment: You always break out of a case at the end.

Comment: Your code will work, but I agree... break always... return at the end.

Comment: It is a style choice - there is no right or wrong answer.

Comment: "You always break out of a case at the end" is just dogma, and is also not true (sometimes falling through to the next case is desired behavior). If you don't need to do anything else in the method, it's fine to return early.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Suppose the user adds Bold and italic on the text, then we dont have to exit the whole swith method right?

Comment: Wouldn't the method execute twice if the user made two selections?

Comment: @BilltheLizard The whole  `onActionItemClicked` method is called again, but the textSelectionMenu dosn't exit or closes down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> using return stays in the switch

This is incorrect.  A `return` statement most definitely does **not** stay in the `switch` statement.  A `return` will return from the method immediately.  The remainder of the code in the method will not be executed.  That is why you do not see the log statement that is after your switch statement when you use `return`.

Either a `break` or a `return` will exit the switch statement.  Either one can suffice.  There is a lot of debate regarding the use of multiple `return` statements in a method.

Some people would prefer that you have only one `return` statement at the end of the method.  This practice has the benefit of least surprise: as you maintain your software and need to make changes, you can add statements after the switch and they will be executed.  You don't need to find each `return` and adjust each one.

Sometimes, however, there are good uses of multiple `return` statements.  For example, if you test for an error condition and `return` immediately, this can keep your code shorter and avoid unnecessarily deep indentation.  Sometimes it requires excess flags and convoluted logic to avoid extra return statements.

Ultimately, consider the clarity and ease of reading and understanding your code months and years in the future.  That is when the difference will be important.  Write your code in the simplest and clearest way possible.  I would recommend breaking your switch statement apart and having separate methods for each block.  Then the statement will be shorter and clearer.  You'll be able to see each of the cases on your screen without scrolling and getting lost in the noise and be able to see each of the `breaks`.  Or use an if-else statement so that you can't be surprised when a `case` falls through because you forgot a `break`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `break` or `return` to exit a `case` block, but `return` will also exit the method immediately. This is why "out of switch" does not get logged when you use return.

Comment: So IT dosn't matter what I choose in this particular case?

Comment: That depends on whether there is code that you want to execute after the switch but within the method. In this instance, no it does not matter.